# Missing file halts boy's first encounter with OGRE3D!

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, ubuntu-9.04, ogre3d

Say - anyone attempted to setup Ogre in Eclipse on Ubuntu?

I'm attempting to run through this here [tutorial](http://www.ogre3d.org/wiki/index.php/IDE_Eclipse#Install_Eclipse), it refers to a file called **bootstrap** in the *eclipse workspace*/*ogreproject*/ directory.

This so called bootstrap is severely absent and as such my attempt has been thwarted.

Comment: I can provide background, but not really an answer.  bootstrap should be a script which generate the configure script using autoconf and the rest of autotools.  Then configure, in turn, should generate your Makefile(s).  However, it looks like the current trunk uses CMake instead of autotools.  Perhaps the wiki is dated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, actually, I guess that's the answer in my comment above.  Check out [the most recently tagged version in the SVN (1.6.2)](https://svn.ogre3d.org/svnroot/ogre/tags/v1-6-2/).  That still uses autotools to generate the Makefile, so you have a bootstrap script there.

The SVN head, however, [is now using CMake](http://freshmeat.net/articles/stop-the-autoconf-insanity-why-we-need-a-new-build-system), so the wiki will need to be updated.

Comment: You are so damn right!  For those that might stumble over this too - you need to install cmake-gui and run it from the Ogre directory.  (And NOT the Ogre/OgreMain directory ;) ).

Answer (score 0):

ah! looks like [this](http://www.ogre3d.org/wiki/index.php/Building_From_Source#Ubuntu_.2F_Kubuntu) advice will do the trick.

seems bootstrap is a part of OIS.

there you go.

Comment: Er, that's the wrong "bootstrap" as it were.  bootstrap is just a common name for a script which generatures a configure script using autotools.  The problem is that the wiki no longer accurately describes how to build from SVN since they've changed build systems.